# Need to store data for session/ transaction in Java

Tags: java, session, factory-pattern

I am exposing some WebServices (Weblogic Jdk 1.6) and in the XML request of those methods there is a MarketType element.

This Xml Element Value I need to access in some Factories POJO's, so the my Factories them self knows that for this "session/transaction" the MarketType is ABC, so that when Code needs an Object from the Factory, the Factory returns the MarketType specific Object..
Right now the MarketType value need to be 'dragged' through all the code and all layers because Factories called a different places in the Code need that value.

So how/where to I store this value? and how do I access it in a safe way?

Here some code as it is today:

```
interface DataFactory {
    PriceCalulator getPriceCalculator(MarketType type);
}

class DataFactoryImpl implements DataFactory {

    public PriceCalulator getPriceCalculator(MarketType type) {
        switch(type) {
            case : DK   {
                return new DKPriceCalculator();
            }
            case : NL {
                return new NLPriceCalculator();
            }    
        }  
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to do something like

```
public XmlCalcResult price(XmlRequest request) {
    ServicePrice impl = new ServicePrice();
    // Set MarkeType in "Global/Session" ..
    MarketType type = SessionScope.setMarketType(request.getMarketType()) 

    return impl.executePrice(ctx, session, request);
}

class ServicePrice {
    public XmlCalcResult executePrice(ctx, session, request) {
       PriceCalulator calc = DataFactoryImpl.getPriceCalculator();

       return new XmlCalcResult(calc.doCalculation()) ;
    }
}

interface DataFactory {
    PriceCalulator getPriceCalculator();
}

class DataFactoryImpl implements DataFactory {

    // Get from "Global/Session" ..
   MarketType type = SessionScope.getMarketType()  


    public PriceCalulator getPriceCalculator() {
        switch(type) {
            case : DK   {
                return new DKPriceCalculator();
            }
            case : NL {
                return new NLPriceCalculator();
            }    
        }  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to store the MarketType element in ThreadLocal so that it can be accessed from different locations down the line. Always call remove() on the ThreadLocal instance just before the thread completes its task. This is important because in servlet containers, threads are reused and may cause memory leaks if ThreadLocal is not cleared. The appropriate place to call set and remove could be a filter.